# How to allow loadView to be sent to my NSViewController?

Tags: macos, cocoa, view, nsviewcontroller

Having discovered that `awakeFromNib` is begin called multiple times, I tried to implement `loadView` in the following way to prevent (nib loading) initialization from repeatedly occurring, with:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [self viewWillLoad];
    [super loadView];
    [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

Looks like a good trick to allowing certain arrays and properties to be set-up in `viewWillLoad`, but `loadView` absolutely won't be called.

Why?

I've done much research about this here and through google.

Comment: Are you using NSViewController?

Comment: When are you expecting `loadView` to be called?

Comment: @PeterHosey I guess the 'new' answer is never. If its not a good idea to do initialization in the init method, then where is a good place using a view or window controller?

Comment: @PeterHosey I see your edit to move OSX. I intended for that to help others reading to quickly know it's a question about OS X. There are many questions with a similar topic regarding iOS, but few about Mac. I bit on many, which caused a charged down the wrong road.

Comment: @PeterHosey Would you consider making an answer with your last comment 'My theory of why...' below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not receiving a `loadView` message because you have this VC and its view in the same nib, with the VC's `view` outlet set to the view. Since the VC already has a view, it has no reason to go load another one.

Answer (score -1):

`loadView` is typically not called if you are using a nib (since `view` is already set). But the real question is why you're trying to fight the view loading process this way. If `awakeFromNib` is being called multiple times, that suggests you have multiple instances of this class. Each will get a call to `awakeFromNib` (that is expected behavior). If this is surprising, you should dig into why you have multiple instances. But you shouldn't try to subvert the view-loading mechanism like this.

Comment: Multiple VCs is one possibility, but not the only one: A single instance of a VC that is archived in one nib and owns another nib will receive two `awakeFromNib` messages.

Comment: Also, whether “`view` is already set” depends on what you mean by “using a nib”. If the VC and view are both in the same nib (the VC in this case should not own any nib), then yes, `view` is already set to the view to which that outlet is connected. If the VC owns a nib and that nib is where the view is, then `view` is not already set, so [`loadView` is called by `view` the first time something tries to access this VC's view](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSViewController/view).

Comment: @PeterHosey & Rob. The multiple calls to `awakeFromNib`, to the best of my understanding is because the one tableview in this VC has a subclassed cell (view based). For each cell that's created, `awakeFromNib` gets called. Interestingly its the same instance for every call. I don't see the point of building a few arrays over and over again... What if this was a large table? I was hoping to find a more elegant way of initializing certain data for the view.

Comment: @David: Nobody is suggesting that you should build your arrays repeatedly. Your `loadView` approach should work (going by the documentation) if the VC had a nib of its own, or if it created its view programmatically (in the overridden `loadView`). My theory of why you're not receiving a `loadView` message is that you have this VC and its view in the same nib, with the VC's `view` outlet set to the view; thus, the VC already has a view, so it has no reason to go load another one.

Comment: Thanks Rob. The picture and question are becoming clearer. The purpose of `awakeFromNib` is not to set up (data) arrays for the view... I've asked the wrong question. Btw, this was less about fighting the view loading process - more about learning the overall process. Per my comment 2 above, there is another big reason for `awakeFromNib` to be called. For those of us who are new and without experience, combining details in the documentation doesn't just happen.